# Android application and video streaming

Tags: android, video, streaming

I have on my website an avi video and I would like that my users application could see it in streaming. How can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can also launch external Video player through following method for streaming. It will display a list of Available video players, can select any player of his own choice.

```
private static void executeIntentForplayVideo(String localPath,
        LTDCommonData ltdCommonData, final Context activity) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    // Stream from remote path
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(finalPath), "video/*");
    //play from sd-card
    // intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
    try {
        List<ResolveInfo> intents = activity.getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (intents != null && intents.size() > 0) {

            activity.startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity,"Please download a video player" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- If you want to create your own media player. [Here is a good example
  with source code.](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/)
- Here is a [development Guid for MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). It will also support
  streaming.